# Get a type from variable and use as argument for generic method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, xna, game-engine

I'm working on some stuff for a simple game engine in xna that I will use for future projects. It's definitely inspired by Unity's framework.
I'm working on a gameobject & component system at the moment and have gotten stuck on cloning a gameobject.

This is how I'm trying to implement it,

```
public static GameObject CloneGameObject(GameObject obj, Vector2 position, float scale)
{
    var clone = new GameObject(); //Create a entirely new gameobject
    foreach (var comp in obj.components) //Clone all the components
    {
        Type t = comp.GetType(); 
        clone.components.Add(Component.CloneComponent<t>()); //This obviously doesn't work
    }
    clone.position = position;
    clone.scale = scale;

    AllGameObjects.Add(clone);
    return clone;
}
```

What I'm getting stuck at is how to get the components type to use as a generic argument.

All I'm doing with the component to clone currently is just changing the owner on the clone:

```
public static TComponent CloneComponent<TComponent>(Component toClone) where TComponent : Component, new()
{
    var clone = new TComponent();

    clone.gameObject = toClone.gameObject;

    return clone;
}
```

The Component system is simple, all components inherit from the Component class.

Example:

```css
class PlayerController : Component
{
    public float jumpForce = 5;
    public float walkSpeed = 2;

    RigidBody rb;
    Collider col;

    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody>();
        col = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>();
    }

    bool canJump { get { return jumps > 0; } }
    int jumps = 1;
    int maxJumps = 1;
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisInputs(Keyboard.GetState(), "Horizontal") * walkSpeed, rb.velocity.Y);
        if (Input.GetKeyOnDown(Keyboard.GetState(), Keys.Space) && canJump)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.X, -jumpForce);
            jumps--;
        }

        if (!col.PlaceIsFree(new Vector2(0, 1)))
            jumps = maxJumps;
            
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

(Cant get code samples to format correctly so I just used a css snippet ://)

Im not asking for anything about cloning itself, just simply how I can get the correct generic argument or if there is another way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change a signature of `CloneComponent` function:

```
public static TComponent CloneComponent<TComponent>(TComponent toClone) where TComponent : Component, new()
```

And then you should invoke this function like:

```
foreach (var comp in obj.components) //Clone all the components
{
    clone.components.Add(Component.CloneComponent(comp));
}
```

You also can use syntactic sugar to simplify invocation code:

```
public static TComponent Clone<TComponent>(this TComponent toClone) where TComponent : Component, new()
{
    if (toClone == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(toClone));
    }

    var clone = new TComponent();

    clone.gameObject = toClone.gameObject;

    return clone;
}
```

And the loop would be:

```
foreach (var comp in obj.components) //Clone all the components
{
    clone.components.Add(comp.Clone());
}
```